# English language and usage?

Tags: discussion

> English Language & Usage

OR

> English Language & its Usage

I think **its** should be there..

What do you think masters of English language?

Comment: As written, it parses as “English Language and English Usage,” which sounds fine.

Comment: Off topic (proofreading request), not constructive (proofreading the Internet, peeving). If there is a specific word or construction you want expert help to understand, please edit to show prior research and rephrase the question.

Comment: As well as what Bradd says, titles get to elide words in all manner of ways.

Comment: don't think in manner of this title I just used another way so I need your help that what I should write? is my english correct? but why downvote> where is my mistake?

Comment: @JavaD I believe your question is being downvoted because it is ambiguous and poorly presented. Users might be expressing their objection to your criticism of the website's name. If you are not criticizing the name then I suggest you rephrase your question and post it to English Language Learners. http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bradd actually it does not sound fine to me. As a matter of public record, it never did. I'm with the OP on this one. It sounds like "Car audio and installation". It is awful, as you do not install a car, you install the car *audio*. Or "Human beings and behavior". Or "Star Trek and episodes". Well, you get the idea. The *and* implies that it connects two things on the same level, while it quite clearly does not. I will refrain from using strong language here, but it is sloppy to say the least.

Comment: @RegDwighт I see your point, but where “car installation” doesn't make sense, “English usage” is an established phrase already used on its own in similar contexts (see [_Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/cgi-bin/book.pl?usage.htm)), and not simply a modifier of _English language._

Comment: It occurs to me that my comment would make a decent answer. Posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing title is just fine! *its* is understood here.

Comment: @Shaona.. hey I am not talking about this title when I want to write this somewhere then my english is right or not? that is only I want to know..:)

Comment: @JavaD When writing about the studying or learning of English, the expression: "English language **and** usage" is appropriate.

Comment: this answer is demonstrably untrue.  look at the first comment under the question: @BraddSzonye thinks it parses as "English Language and English Usage."

Answer (score 2):

*English language* and *English usage* are both common phrases related to the tongue, as in [*The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*](http://www.ahdictionary.com/) and [*Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage.*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/cgi-bin/book.pl?usage.htm) Therefore, *language and usage* is simply a compound modifier indicating that the site emphasizes both aspects of English: not only its structure, meaning, and history (language), but also how to read and write it fluently (usage).

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a probably downvoted question asking why it’s *“& usage”* and if “English” doesn’t encompass its usage.